# How to keep InputField keyboard open when focus is lost?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making a typing game where the user types in words that fall down the screen, and I have buttons at the top that act as powerups (nuke, freeze, etc...) when the user presses them.

Now, when the user clicks one of the powerup buttons at the top of the screen, the keyboard will momentarily close before `ButtonClicked` re-opens it and it looks quite buggy. **How do I make it so that when the user clicks one of the buttons at the top the keyboard stays open the whole time?**

Currently, I have added a listener on the button that will re-open the keyboard.

```cs
myButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClicked);

void ButtonClicked()
{
    //DoStuff();
    inputField.ActivateInputField();
}
```

This is what it looks like now. I have to click once to get rid of the keyboard, and then once again on the button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkGOK.jpg

I tried overriding some InputField functions with a custom class but to no avail.

```cs
public class CustomInputField: InputField
{ 
     public override void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
     {
         Debug.Log ("Overrides InputField.Deselect");
     }

     public override void DeactivateInputField()
     {
         Debug.Log ("Overrides InputField.DeactivateInputField");
     }

}
```

The first method doesn't accomplish what I want, and the second method `DeactivateInputField()` gives me

> error CS0506: `CustomInputField.DeactivateInputField': cannot override inherited member`InputField.DeactivateInputField' because it is not marked virtual, abstract or override.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TouchScreenKeyboard.open` Function to leave the Keyboard open over time (here the Link to the Unity Manual: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html). I would then aswell try to not use Update for this there should be another way to do so in your script.

Your error Otherwise might be caused because you try to override a function that is like the error said not Virtual Abstract nor Override so you aren't allowed to do that. To this it is an Unity class so you won't be able to change this aswell.

Another Thing you could try would be LateUpdate that wouldn't be perfect but it may Help your case here an Example:

```
LateUpdate()
{
if(!TouchScreenKeyboard.visible)
          TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()/inputField.ActivateInputField();
};
```

Comment: I updated the question with a video and some more clarification. I also tried using `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()` instead of having an InputField but the problem persisted.

Comment: Ok, then I am not sure about the Problem aswell. I Just Update my answer a bit with my last idea to the Topic

Comment: I have this same issue as well as many others - https://forum.unity.com/threads/keyboard-hides-when-tap-anywhere.784280/

I hope they are able to find a fix soon. If you happen to find one, please let the community know.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dumbest code I've ever written, but it does the trick:

```
public class FocusInputField : TMP_InputField
{
    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        this.StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public override void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnDeselect(eventData);
        this.StartCoroutine(ReselectCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator ReselectCoroutine()
    {
        yield return null;

        this.ActivateInputField();
        this.Select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The input field opens the system keyboard and your control over it is limited. If I were you I would create UI keyboard in my app which could be customized in any way and would guarantee same results on different devices/systems.

Comment: I want the user's native keyboard to show up so they can practice their typing on the keyboard they use in their day to day life. Is there anyway to get this to work without making a different keyboard?

Comment: I see the point. Well try with a Raycast, maybe you will be able to cast a ray and trigger action instantly but I have not tested.