# How to override Text Mesh Pro functions in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making a unity app with many TMP input fields and I would like the user to be able to interact with the screen while keeping the keyboard open. As they type, I present many images based on their text.

I found this thread:
[How to keep InputField keyboard open when focus is lost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644419/how-to-keep-inputfield-keyboard-open-when-focus-is-lost/70025893#70025893)

asking the same question with a possible solution here:

```
public class FocusInputField : TMP_InputField
{
    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        this.StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public override void OnDeselect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnDeselect(eventData);
        this.StartCoroutine(ReselectCoroutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator ReselectCoroutine()
    {
        yield return null;

        this.ActivateInputField();
        this.Select();
    }
}
```

I want to try this solution and override some TMP functions, but I dont know how to implement this. I created a new script and added this this code, but since its not a monobehavior, i cant add this new class to my gameobject. How can I do this?

Comment: `since its not a monobehavior` ... but it is a [`TMP_InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html) which is a [`Selectable`](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Selectable.html) which is a [`UIBehaviour`](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.UIBehaviour.html) which **IS** a `MonoBehaviour`  => you can attach it to GameObjects ... how about you go ahead and simply try it before claiming it is not possible ;)

Comment: just try it :"v

Comment: Just make sure that the script name also matches exactly the class name `FocusInputField.cs` (the extension is not visible within Unity itself but in your file browser)

Answer (score 0):

I had the file name misspelled! Thank you everybody

Unfortunately the fix doesnt work. The keyboard still disappears and then reappears, with no way to actually make it go away.